# How to connect to the internet from DPDK running in a VM

Tags: networking, dpdk

DPDK is a library for kernel bypass packet processing: https://www.dpdk.org/. F-Stack is a TCP/IP library built atop it: https://github.com/F-Stack/f-stack. I've set up a Linux VMWare VPN with two NICs, have given the second to DPDK, and am attempting to run a very simple test application on it that uses F-Stack and DPDK to connect to the internet. This is however failing (fails to connect).

When I attempt to run a simple server, it also fails, in that I cannot connect to it from Curl or a browser running in the VM.

The test application displays no errors (the DPDK initialisation works fine), and behaves correctly when the DPDK stuff is replaced with standard Linux networking functions that don't bypass the kernel.

My question is, is there anything I need to do to make the above setup work, so that DPDK running on the second NIC in my VM can connect to the internet? E.g. set up some kind of mapping somewhere, or change the virtual network connection type on the VM (currently set to NAT). My networking knowledge is limited so it's quite possible I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: Your question is not clear, from the current description are you stating you are running some kind of simple server program on DPDK NIC 2? if this is understanding is right, how is the curl request from the current VM redirected to DPDK NIC?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I'm trying to run a simple TCP client. I also tested a simple TCP server, which also didn't work. For the server I didn't do anything to redirect the curl request from the VM to the NIC 2 (used by DPDK) on the VM; my question is do I need to do some kind of redirect, and if so how do I do it.

Comment: if your intent is to use DPDK-TCP-Server, you will be sending traffic to NIC-2 (DPDK port). Hence your TCP client  should be sending packets to VM NIC 2 (DPDK interface). You are aware that Linux Kernel can not send packets to DPDK userspace from kernel space directly on the NIC-2 right?  hence I assume you are running TCP-CLIENT on Host or another VM if this is true `are you receiving packets on DPDK-TCP_SEDRVER`?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the Linux Kernel can not send packets to DPDK userspace from kernel space directly on the NIC-2. I know how to write a network server but I know very little about networking, hence I was running DPDK-TCP-Server on the same VM as TCP-CLIENT. Is there a way to make the TCP-CLIENT send messages to the DPDK-TCP-Server on the same server (make it send to the VM NIC 2 DPDK interface)? The other part of my question is, if I run a DPDK-TCP_CLIENT, do I need to set up some kind of mapping so it can connect to the internet, given VM NIC 1(Kernel) can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answer based on the updates from the comments as

Send packets directly between userspace and Kernel using DPDK, there are 3 options

1. KNI PMD
2. TUN/TAP PMD
3. veth pair with one interface to DPDK via PCAP PMD.

the easiest way to try it out is by using DPDK `example/skeleton` with `./build/basicfwd -l 3 --vdev=net_tap0,ifaace=dpdk-kerenl0 -w [pcie bus address for DPDK NIC-2]`. This will allow packets to send and receive over kernel via DPDK (where DPDK will act as pass-through). You can modify the `basicfwd.c` to process packets which you desire too.

If using FSTACK, I humbly request to check `carrier` section `https://github.com/F-Stack/f-stack/blob/dev/README.md` this makes use of KNI or veth to accomplish the same